# I would like to develop function related to QRCode reader. Is there anyway I can debug by Simulator

Tags: codenameone

Can I debug my program for QRcode reader with cn1 simulator without a camera?
The simulator doesn't include a camera to scan QRcode. How do I debug my program for QRCode reading?

Answer (score 1):

Currently we don't support that. Notice that you can use the `isSimulator()` method (in `CN` and `Display`) to create a special case that lets you add a manual way to test the QR code.

E.g. instead of showing a scan button just add a text field and paste in the text matching the QR code content. Then use that to invoke the rest of your code.